# DNS for domain shows old website for www version

Tags: domains, dns

I bought 2 domains form GoDaddy but with both I am seeing the same problems in that the domain on the `www` version goes to the old site which is still being hosted.

I have checked the IntoDNS website and in the `www` record it shows:

```
Your www.example.com A record is:
www.example.com -> example.typepad.com -> cname-cloudflare.typepad.com ->
```

What can I do to stop this from happening?

Will this eventually be automatically removed and fix itself? Though obviously it's not automatically fixed itself in the long drawn out expiry process...

It's been quite a while for one of them and still hasn't propagated for the `www`. I'm not having any problems with the normal `example.com` part of the site.

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: If it goes over 48 hours, then there is a problem. If the problem does not clear up, please leave your domain names in the comments, if you do not mind of course, and I or someone will look at your records to help.

Comment: Please share the domain so we can look up the records, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may need to park your domains at your domain registrar and wait for atleast 24-hours for the DNS propagation and after that you are free to host your domains where you may want by adding records in DNS Zone File.